# Target size (torch.Size([32, 9])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 10]))

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, size

I have 10 classes. I have a model such as;

```
from brevitas.nn import QuantLinear, QuantReLU
import torch.nn as nn

# Setting seeds for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(0)

model = nn.Sequential(
      QuantLinear(input_size, hidden1, bias=True, weight_bit_width=weight_bit_width),
      nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden1),
      nn.Dropout(0.5),
      QuantReLU(bit_width=act_bit_width),
      QuantLinear(hidden1, hidden2, bias=True, weight_bit_width=weight_bit_width),
      nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden2),
      nn.Dropout(0.5),
      QuantReLU(bit_width=act_bit_width),
      QuantLinear(hidden2, hidden3, bias=True, weight_bit_width=weight_bit_width),
      nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden3),
      nn.Dropout(0.5),
      QuantReLU(bit_width=act_bit_width),
      QuantLinear(hidden3, num_classes, bias=True, weight_bit_width=weight_bit_width)
)

model.to(device)
```

and I have defined my training phase as:

```
def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion):
    losses = []
    # ensure model is in training mode
    model.train()    
    
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):        
        inputs, target = data['pointcloud'].to(device).float(), data['category'].to(device)
        target = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()   
                
        # forward pass
        output = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(output, target.float())
        
        # backward pass + run optimizer to update weights
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        # keep track of loss value
        losses.append(loss.data.cpu().numpy()) 
           
    return losses
```

As I run the training code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tqdm import tqdm, trange

# Setting seeds for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

running_loss = []
running_test_acc = []
t = trange(num_epochs, desc="Training loss", leave=True)

for epoch in t:
        loss_epoch = train(model, train_loader, optimizer,criterion)
        test_acc = test(model, valid_loader)
        t.set_description("Training loss = %f test accuracy = %f" % (np.mean(loss_epoch), test_acc))
        t.refresh() # to show immediately the update           
        running_loss.append(loss_epoch)
        running_test_acc.append(test_acc)
```

I get an error as:

> Target size (torch.Size([32, 9])) must be the same as input size
> (torch.Size([32, 10]))

Please help me about what can be possibly the solution. I have added one hot encoding because I have seen some solutions like that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code error is pretty straightforward - the `criterion` (that you didn't show here in the code) expects both the `input` and the `target` arguments to be the same size, but they're not.

The problem is that you're using `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target)` without telling it how many classes you need for one-hot encoding; it is then infered as the largest values in `target` `+1` (see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html). You should change it to `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target, num_classes=10)`

Comment: I will try that and let you know, thank you very much for the response

Comment: If you can help me with this problem I will fully understand the general idea, I am really appreciated for your answer but it didn't solve my full problem. I have explained the general problem at the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043492/found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-908-9080