# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [908, 9080]

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch, conv-neural-network, size

I have a dataset, I have reconfigured my tensors as a single 3072 sized line array. I have reconfigured the valid dataset and training dataset. You can find all of the information about my train, valid dataset and their shapes below:

> Train dataset size:  3991
>
> Valid dataset size:  908
>
> Number of classes:  10
>
> Sample pointcloud shape:  torch.Size([3072])

I have a test function defined as below,:

```
import torch
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def test(model, test_loader):    
    # ensure model is in eval mode
    model.eval() 
    y_true = []
    y_pred = []
   
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            inputs, target = data['pointcloud'].to(device).float(), data['category'].to(device)
            target = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target, num_classes=10)
            output_orig = model(inputs)
            # run the output through sigmoid
            output = torch.sigmoid(output_orig)  
            # compare against a threshold of 0.5 to generate 0/1
            pred = (output.detach().cpu().numpy() > 0.5) * 1
            target = target.cpu().float()
            y_true.extend(target.tolist()) 
            y_pred.extend(pred.reshape(-1).tolist())
        
    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

As I run this code with:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tqdm import tqdm, trange

# Setting seeds for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

running_loss = []
running_test_acc = []
t = trange(num_epochs, desc="Training loss", leave=True)

for epoch in t:
        loss_epoch = train(model, train_loader, optimizer,criterion)
        test_acc = test(model, valid_loader)
        t.set_description("Training loss = %f test accuracy = %f" % (np.mean(loss_epoch), test_acc))
        t.refresh() # to show immediately the update           
        running_loss.append(loss_epoch)
        running_test_acc.append(test_acc)
```

I get an error message as:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-40645ae42a17> in <module>()
     13 for epoch in t:
     14         loss_epoch = train(model, train_loader, optimizer,criterion)
---> 15         test_acc = test(model, valid_loader)
     16         t.set_description("Training loss = %f test accuracy = %f" % (np.mean(loss_epoch), test_acc))
     17         t.refresh() # to show immediately the update

3 frames
<ipython-input-27-8ed1b7ca6d78> in test(model, test_loader)
     21             y_pred.extend(pred.reshape(-1).tolist())
     22 
---> 23     return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    209 
    210     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 211     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    212     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    213     if y_type.startswith("multilabel"):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     82     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     83     """
---> 84     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     85     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     86     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    335         )
    336 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [908, 9080]
```

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
> samples: [908, 9080]

I am stucked with this problem for couple of days, if anyone can help I will be really appreciated.

Comment: You are calling `accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)` with a different number of samples in `y_true` and `y_pred`.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information about what should I do to fix it?

Comment: You should double check how you create `y_pred`, because it has 10 times more values than necessary. I would check the output of `pred.reshape(-1).tolist()`. My guess is that the torch model returns 10 values per samples (one value per class), whereas the target has only one value per samples.

Answer (score 0):

You should flatten the `target` the same way you're flattening `pred`; right now your `y_true` variable is a list of 980 10-dimensional vectors, while your `y_pred` is a list of 9800 values.

However, it's not clear what kind of accuracy you are interested in; the way you're computing labels would be fitting for a multi-label classification. If it's a simple 10-way classification, you shouldn't compute the accuracy on one-hot encoded vectors; instead you should be giving a list of integers in <0; 9> as `target` (so - no one-hot encoding) and a similar list as a predicted class as pred (so - argmax of predicted probabilities). I'm not sure what your task is exactly, but make sure you make it right.